# Determine Stability of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems

> Determine the stability of the following dynamical system:
>   $\begin{bmatrix}.3&.4&.5\\.3&.4&.5\\.3&.4&.5\end{bmatrix}$.

So, firstly, we find the eigenvalues of this matrix. These are $\lambda$ = 0, .9. However, after that, I have no idea what to do, mainly because to find stability, you need vectors in the form of $a \pm bi$. Is this system thus unstable? Can somebody help me?

Comment: $\lambda = 0, 1.2$?

Comment: @GNUSupporter ? I bleieve it is .9

Comment: Consider $v = (1,1,1)^T$. (i.e. add up all columns)

Comment: Yes, but does that prove it is not stable? I just don't know how to go asbout this process.

Comment: I dunno dynamical systems, but a [Wiki search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_dynamical_system#Solution_of_linear_dynamical_systems) might answer your question.

Comment: This is unstable. I suppose you have a discrete-time dynamical system of the form $x(k+1)=Ax(k)$ where $A$ is the matrix you described. If there exists one eigenvalue lying outside the unit circle (such as $1.2$) then the equilibrium $x=0$ is unstable.